# How to generate a JSON with a property containing .(dot) in one of the property in Custom Policies?

Tags: json, xml, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to generate JSON in custom policies for request body of an API.
The required API request body is [Required Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzZWQ.png) but while using the below code

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateAMNotificationRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
    <InputClaims></InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="something:abc.0:user.property" DataType="string" Value="value" />
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

It generates the following JSON [current JSON using above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOr0Q.png)

Is generating the JSON in above format possible ? Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the dot with "\u002E". "\u" is used in JSON to insert an ASCII character and "002E" is the ASCII hex value for "."

Comment: not working, it is generating something:abc\\u002E:user

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn custom policies supported escaping when generating JSON. I guess not. In that case you might have to just do it manually. It might be a bit of a pain depending on how many claims you want to use, but FormatStringClaim and FormatStringMultipleClaim should help. There's an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74340328/20418916) with an example