# ClaimsTransformation of type GenerateJson escape "."

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

So I wrote this little transformation

```
 <ClaimsTransformation Id="REST-AddToGroup-JsonPayloadTransformation" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
     <InputClaims>
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="graphUserUri" TransformationClaimType="@odata.id" />
     </InputClaims>
     <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="graphDataPayload" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
     </OutputClaims>
 </ClaimsTransformation>
```

where graphUserUri would be something like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/d2e7379b-f79a-4eff-af83-f7b3f3bededd

I would hope to get the graphDataPayload to be:

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/d2e7379b-f79a-4eff-af83-f7b3f3bededd"
}
```

but this is generated:

```
{
  "@odata": { "id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/cd223062-d6ad-4062-8d0f-e95dfbe817c4" }
}
```

According to the documentation, this works as intended but I can't find a way to escape the "."
I've tried to set the name to "@odata\.id" but that just made it worse as it escaped the "\" and still created a child object in the json

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky way of going around it.

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="REST-AddToGroup-JsonPayloadTransformation" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value='{{  "@odata.id " : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}" }}' />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="graphDataPayload" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

This will generate the proper claim in the right format but the solution is not ideal.